# Ansible Delegate_to WinRM

Tags: windows, powershell, automation, ansible

I am using the ansible vsphere_guest module to spin up a base windows machine on a VMWare environment. In my playbook, to do this I set `Hosts: 127.0.0.1 connection: local`. The reason I am doing this is I beleive im not targeting this playbook at any particular host, as I dont have one yet. I instead want to run the playbook locally.

When this runs, I get a new shiny windows server VM. What I now want to do is rename that VM's computer name. To do this I am trying to upload and run a powershell script like so  `rename_host.ps1 $newHostname`. As I understand, I need to use the script module to do this. However, this time I want to target my brand new VM, which I get the IP address of through a fact, `{{ newvm_ipaddress }}`.

However, when I try and run this script with `delegate_to: "{{ newvm_ipaddress}}"`, its trying to run as SSH. SSH wont work, im targeting a windows machine with remote powershell.

is there any way to set the connection to use winRM in the context of delegate_to? Perhaps there is a better way of doing this?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

I managed to work out how to solve it.  The answer is the ansible module 'add_host'. I have a play under vsphere_guest as follows. This creates a new in memory host, which can then be accessed by a different play.

`- add_host group=new_machine name={{ vm_ipaddress }} ansible_connection=winrm`

After this, I then have a new play that can now target this host.

`- host: new_machine`

Also to note, variables do not span across different hosts. The solution was to use the set_fact module in play A, which can then be accessed from within play B

`-set_fact:
  vm_ipaddress: "{{ hw_eth0.ipaddresses[1] }}" #hw_eth0 is the fact returned from the vsphere_guest module`

Answer (score 1):

What about updating the inventory with the new hosts name and with ssh winrm connection params before using delegate_to, or perhaps setting some default catch-all naming scheme with these params?

For example:

```
[databases]
db-[a:f].example.com:5986 ansible_user=Administrator ansible_connection=winrm ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore
```

Comment: I could manually update the inventory file with the IP address of the new VM, but how do I do that automatically when the fact comes back from vsphere_guest for the new IP address?